# Temporary water supply shut off to a gas oil fired furance

Tags: boiler, well, filter

I have a oil fired furnace that supplies all hot water to the house (the house is on well water)including base board heat. If I shut the main supply off where it enters the house in order to install a whole house water filter, can i just turn the water supply back on or are there other steps needed? The water will be off for a few hours only.

Comment: Terminology. A furnace in home heating context heats air which is blown around. A boiler heats water (even if it doen't make steam, still called a boiler.) So, you have a boiler.

Comment: why does the title contain the word `gas`?

Answer (score 2):

Should be no special effort needed.

Normally the hydronic heating loop is isolated from the domestic water supply - water can be fed into it but cannot come back out of it into the source supply.

The water heating coil for domestic hot water is pretty much a piece of pipe sitting in the hot boiler water - or you may have a tank full of hot water with a pipe from the heating supply coiled up in the bottom of it. Neither should be overly affected by turning off the water for a few hours.

What will often happen is that crud in the pipes will be loosened up by the inevitable air bubbles trapped in the pipes and blowing out of them when you turn the water back on - that can clog aerator screens, so you may want to remove those and flush the pipes until the water runs clear when you turn the water back on, before reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

After you turn the water back on then just make sure to purge any air by opening a sink faucet. If your boiler system sucks in any air then it will lose heating efficiency.